# Iterate over list of items and extract the data for the list from web browser and append the data frame as final output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to extract the stock market related data from the web browser. I am able to open the web browser and extract the data for one stock.

Below is the python code for “One stock” which opens the web browser with Selenium Webdriver and extract the data from the web page using the Beautifulsoup

This is very basic code which requires simplification and be able to extract the data for list of stock like the below

```
stock_list=['Infosys' , 'Reliance industries', 'wipro' ]
```

I am not sure how to extract the data for multiple item in the list as mentioned above and to simplify it based on this.

Python code to extract the data for one stock.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.tickertape.in/stocks/")
browser.maximize_window()
inputElement=browser.find_element_by_id('search-stock-input')
inputElement.click()
inputElement.send_keys('Infosys')
inputElement.click()
inputElement = wait(browser, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search-stock-input")))
inputElement.click()
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

page = requests.get(browser.current_url,headers=headers)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

ScriptName = []
ScriptName_elem = soup.find_all( class_ = 'jsx-2256451 security-name')

for item in ScriptName_elem:
    ScriptName.append(item.text)

   
intrinsic_value = []
intrinsic_value_elem = soup.find_all( class_ = 'jsx-3277407410 jsx-1058798148 lh-138 text-13 commentary-desc')

for item in intrinsic_value_elem:
intrinsic_value.append(item.text)



Returns_vs_FD_rates = []
Returns_vs_FD_rates_elem = soup.find_all( class_ = 'jsx-3947392323 jsx-1058798148 lh-138 text-13 commentary-desc')

for item in Returns_vs_FD_rates_elem:
    Returns_vs_FD_rates.append(item.text)
       

Divident_Returns = []
Divident_Returns_elem = soup.find_all( class_ = 'jsx-566496888 jsx-1058798148 lh-138 text-13 commentary-desc')

for item in Divident_Returns_elem:
    Divident_Returns.append(item.text)
    
    

Entry_Point = []
Entry_Point_elem = soup.find_all( class_ = 'jsx-3697483086 jsx-1058798148 lh-138 text-13 commentary-desc')

for item in Entry_Point_elem:
    Entry_Point.append(item.text)


Red_Flag_Indicator = []
Red_Flag_Indicator_elem = soup.find_all( class_ = 'jsx-1920835126 jsx-1058798148 relative no-select tooltip-holder')

for item in Red_Flag_Indicator_elem:
    Red_Flag_Indicator.append(item.text)
    
    

Red_Flag_Indicator_Reason = []
Red_Flag_Indicator_Reason_elem = soup.find_all( class_ = 'jsx-1920835126 jsx-1058798148 lh-138 text-13 commentary-desc')

for item in Red_Flag_Indicator_Reason_elem:
    Red_Flag_Indicator_Reason.append(item.text)
    
    
df_array = []

for ScriptName_n, intrinsic_value_n,Returns_vs_FD_rates_n,Divident_Returns_n,Entry_Point_n,Red_Flag_Indicator_n,Red_Flag_Indicator_Reason_n in zip(ScriptName,intrinsic_value,Returns_vs_FD_rates,Divident_Returns,Entry_Point,Red_Flag_Indicator,Red_Flag_Indicator_Reason):
    df_array.append({'ScriptName': ScriptName_n, 'intrinsic_value': intrinsic_value_n, 'Returns_vs_FD_rates' : Returns_vs_FD_rates_n, 'Divident_Returns' : Divident_Returns_n, 'Entry_Point' :  Entry_Point_n, 
                     'Red_Flag_Indicator' : Red_Flag_Indicator_n , 'Red_Flag_Indicator_Reason' :  Red_Flag_Indicator_Reason_n })

df = pd.DataFrame(df_array)
df
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What data do you require?

Comment: @QHarr, i want to extract the 7 data points from web page which is added to the data frame at the end. This code works well by extracting for one item that has been passed through inputElement.send_keys(key) , but i want to perform repeatedly by passing a list of items to extract the similar data for those list of items.

Comment: Security name as scriptName, intrinsic_value, Returns_vs_FD_rates, Divident_Returns, Entry_Point, Red_Flag_Indicator etc

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see I needed to scroll down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the same APIs the page does. The first API to get the id, and security name, for the stock to use for the second API which returns those checklist items.
If you create a list of dictionaries, one dictionary per ticker, you can then convert to a dataframe at end. If I have missed an item let me know. I also chose to store a lot of the other data e.g. low, high etc in another dictionary called `other_data`.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

other_data = {}
results = []
stock_list = ['Infosys', 'Reliance industries', 'wipro']

with requests.Session() as s:
    for ticker in stock_list:
        try:
            r = s.get(
                f'https://api.tickertape.in/search?text={ticker.lower()}&types=stock,brands,index,etf,mutualfund').json()
            stock_id = r['data']['stocks'][0]['sid']
            name = r['data']['stocks'][0]['name']
            other_data[stock_id] = r
            r = s.get(
                f'https://api.tickertape.in/stocks/investmentChecklists/{stock_id}?type=basic').json()
            d = {i['title']: i['description'] for i in r['data']}
            d = {**{'Security': name}, **other_data[stock_id]['data']['stocks'][0]['quote'], **{
                'marketCap': other_data[stock_id]['data']['stocks'][0]['marketCap']},  **d}
            results.append(d)
        except Exception as e:
            print(ticker, e)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df
```

Comment: Such a great help and simplified it very well. Code works very well. Can i request you to just add one item in the Other_data such as “High” so that i add few based on the example.

Comment: Sure. Can it wait until a little later today? Values are associated with keys e.g. `other_data['INFY']['data']['stocks'][0]['quote']` then `other_data['INFY']['data']['stocks'][0]['quote']['high']` etc....

Comment: Sure I will wait. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Any help on this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. I need to learn how you have simplified my junk code and learn from it.

Comment: if i want to add the marketCap along with Quote, can i use like **other_data[stock_id][‘data’][‘stocks’][0][‘marketCap’]

Comment: if i use **other_data[stock_id][‘data’][‘stocks’][0][‘marketCap’] to pull the marketCap but it is not working. Is there any reason?

Comment: is `other_data[stock_id][‘data’][‘stocks’][0][‘marketCap’]` a dictionary?

Comment: I added next to quote command as you have added for quote. I thought that other_data is a nested dictionary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236338/discussion-between-qharr-and-user51988).

Comment: I think you have modified the original answer. Thanks for that, I believe that i added the same but missed the curly brackets.

Comment: Hi, Yes I did. I pinged you from chat linked above but not sure it worked as it didn't intellisense your username.

Comment: this is working fine for most of tickers, but say ticker : KHAICHEM, it is not working. 

api call : https://api.tickertape.in/search?text=khaichem&types=stock,index,etf,mutualfund 

isn't giving any result. However ticker exists and we also have result in network request. 

it isn't working fine for 10-15% tickers (total: 1600).